# Count the users created within last week in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

How to use carbon and count the users created in the last 7 days. On blade, I have a table that shows the total of users created per day that has this syntax (example is for today)

```
$getusertoday = MemberProfile::where('encoded_by', '=', $profile->name)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )->count();
```

But in the last column, which is the Weekly Total, I must total everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$getusertoday = MemberProfile::where('encoded_by', '=', $profile->name)
        ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-7 days')) )->count();
```